# Update the database with cell edit using QT and SQLite

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, qtableview

I'm creating an application with SQLite database access that displays database search in QTableView. Search is looking up all columns. Now I would like to be able to edit cells and save to the database. I seem to be able to edit the cells but data is not saved.

```
void MainWindow::on_search_box_textChanged(const QString &arg1)
{
QSqlQueryModel *GetTable = new QSqlTableModel(ui->tableView);

if(!arg1.isEmpty())
{
    GetTable->setQuery(QString("SELECT * FROM Cour WHERE (Date LIKE '""%"+arg1+"%""' OR Name LIKE '""%"+arg1+"%""' OR bill LIKE '""%"+arg1+"%""' OR [B O L] LIKE '""%"+arg1+"%""' OR SO LIKE '""%"+arg1+"%""' OR ETA LIKE '""%"+arg1+"%""' OR Description LIKE '""%"+arg1+"%""' );"));
    ui->tableView->setModel(GetTable);
    ui->tableView->setAlternatingRowColors(GetTable);
    ui->tableView->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Stretch);

}
if(arg1.isEmpty())
{
    GetTable->clear();
    ui->tableView->clearFocus();
    ui->tableView->setModel(GetTable);
}
}
```

This is the code I use to display the data in QTableView. I have tried changing between QSqlTableModel and QSqlQueryModel. Based on docs and hours of googling it appears as if the QTableView should update the database accordingly when the cell is edited. I must be missing something.

At first, I thought it might be caused by database without a primary key but the situation is the same in both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. The thing I was missing was the setFilter() with a properly crafted query.

In `QSqlTableModel` as oppose to `QSqlQueryModel`'s `setQuery()` we should use `setFilter()` which is a `WHERE` part of SQL query and `setTable()` which is `"Select * FROM tablename"`. Now to make table editable via QTableView all we have to do is use `setEditStrategy()`. There is couple of options to chose from but the one I needed was `setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnFieldChange)`.

```
void MainWindow::on_search_box_textChanged(const QString &arg1)
{
QSqlTableModel *GetTable = new QSqlTableModel(ui->tableView);

if(!arg1.isEmpty()){
    GetTable->setTable("DHL");
    GetTable->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnFieldChange);
    GetTable->setFilter(QString("Date LIKE '""%"+arg1+"%""' OR Name LIKE '""%"+arg1+"%""' OR bill LIKE '""%"+arg1+"%""' OR [B O L] LIKE '""%"+arg1+"%""' OR SO LIKE '""%"+arg1+"%""' OR ETA LIKE '""%"+arg1+"%""' OR Description LIKE '""%"+arg1+"%""';"));
    GetTable->select();

    QTableView *tableview = new QTableView();
    ui->tableView->setModel(GetTable);
    ui->tableView->hideColumn(7); // don't show the ID
    ui->tableView->setAlternatingRowColors(GetTable);
    ui->tableView->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Stretch);
    ui->tableView->show();
}
else
{
    GetTable->clear();
    ui->tableView->clearFocus();
    ui->tableView->setModel(GetTable);
}
```

I hope someone will find it useful.